# Setting up google analytics for desktop application

Tags: c#, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a desktop application written in C#. I want to collect user statistics in google analytics. For instance I want to know when user pressed on specific button and what was value in text control when he did it.

I am sending events data as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide?hl=uk). I tried to do this either with [WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399819/c-sharp-measurement-protocol-transaction) and also with [WebClient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have set up new google analytics account. When I was asked what I want to track (website or mobile app) I have selected mobile app (there was no choice for desktop apps).

The problem is that I don't see any data in my Google Analytics account. I know it may take some time while new data will appear there but I have waited for 3 days. And also I don't see anything in real time view when I test my application ( I also have some websites with analytics connected and when I browse them I see new pageviews in realtime section).

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is the code that I use:

```
    private static string _googleURL = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
    private static string _gaid = "UA-12345678-9";

    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            string data = "";
            data += "v=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1");
            data += "&" + "tid" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_gaid);
            data += "&" + "cid" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            data += "&" + "t" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("event");
            data += "&" + "ec" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testevent");
            data += "&" + "ea" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testaction");
            data += "&" + "el" + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testlabel");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.UploadString(_googleURL, "POST", data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about creating a small console application that just sends a single event to GA? If that works then work out why it is different. Otherwise you have a nice short re-create you can share here.

Comment: I have a small test application which just sends event on startup but it doesn't work as well. I even captured traffic and I see POST request to google and 200 answer from google. The problem is that I don't see it in my analytics account.

Comment: So, show us what you are doing that does not work. This will allow others to re-create what you are doing (rather than guessing). Summary: *show us your code*.